# Encoding issues when saving JSON to a file, howto save as UTF-8?

Tags: java, utf-8, gson, fileoutputstream, filewriter

For example JSON objects contain strings like `쏘리` but after saving it to a file I see `????`

```
try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    gson.toJson(jsonObject, writer);
}
```

How can I fix it? Can I set `UTF-8` charset in this code somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  try:

```
try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(path),"UTF-8")) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    gson.toJson(jsonObject, writer);
}
```

So do not create `FileWriter` but `OutputStreamWriter` that allows you to set the encoding to `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. And for reading from a file we can use: `try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(reader, JsonObject.class); }`